# Angular q.all instant vs delayed responses

Tags: javascript, angularjs, real-time, angular-promise, q

I have a methodology question.  Currently I am using `$q.all` to capture multiple promises in a single return, then processing all the results as single request.

ie:   `$q.all([promise1(),promise2(),promise3(),promise(4),promise5()])..then(function(response){ ...}`

However, I am noticing that sometimes different promises are being returned at significantly different time frames.  All the promises are http calls to third party sites.  When any particular promise is delayed by say 8 seconds...or 14 seconds, then the final results of all promises are delayed by that same duration.  The weakest...rather 'slowest'...link syndrome.

What is another method that I can use to call all the promises at the same time yet still allow for results to be processed, and viewed by the user, as they come in?  To NOT wait on all of them to be returned before processing them all at once?

Comment: Don't group them in `all`. Instead use them separately.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you could just use them separately, but if you really want to call them all at the same time and handle them in one promise, you can use the `notify`-callback of the promise. I've created an extension to `$q` that uses this `notify()` function to resolve the promises as one:

```
app.run(function($q){
    $q.each = function(promises){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        promises.forEach(function(promise){
            promise.then(function(data){
                deferred.notify(data);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

This is a pretty naive implementation that doesn't handle errors for instance, but it gives you an idea of what's involved.

Then you'd just use it like this:

```
var promises = [promise1(),promise2(),promise3(),promise(4),promise5()];

$q.each(promises).then(null, null, function(data){
    console.log(data);  // This is called when each promise resolves.
});
```

[Here's a Plunker showing this in action](https://embed.plnkr.co/IB00i8UpmcBWJH9sdVFG/)

Comment: Thanks Nikolak - this is more of what I am looking for.  It gives me some ideas now and I am going to work on implementing something like this over the weekend.  Will post back with questions and/or results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the methods like `then()` or `$q.all()` do not determine how the promises execute; they merely establish the semantics for when you want to respond.  What I mean is, the promises start running when you create them even though a fluent reading of `myPromise.then(doSomething)` might seem to imply otherwise.

Combine that with the fact that `$q.all` doesn't so much "combine promises" as it *creates a new promise that resolves or rejects based on the resolution or rejection status of the original promises*; and that a promise is not limited to only a single handler...

```
promise1.then(function () {
    //stuff that only cares about promise1 and needn't wait for the others
});
$q.all(promise1, promise2, ...).then(function () {
    //stuff that can't be done until everything finishes
});
```